# Struct memory allocation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a C project with pointers and structs, and right now facing this problem:
There is a structure

```
struct Customer
{
    char Name[80];
    char Address[40];
    int ID;
    int Pnumber;
};
```

and I am gonna make a dynamic array of this structs with *line_count* number of members. I use this code, but it crashes a program:

```
struct Customer* ph;
ph = (struct Customer*)malloc(line_count * sizeof(struct Customer));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code alone cannot crash your program (unless `line_count` happens to be a very big number and you don't check if `ph!=NULL` before using it)... post a minimum compilable example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Do you check for `NULL` returned from `malloc()`?

Comment: Is the crash when you try to use the ph var or when you create it?

Comment: Crashes come in MANY forms.  Please describe your crash exactly.  Is there an error message with it?  A particular seg-fault?  

Imagine if we came to you, and said, "My car won't move?".   It could be out of gas, out of oil, dead-battery, flat-tires, stuck in the mud, upside down, you lost the key, etc, etc.... if you don't describe the problem, its very hard for us to help.

Comment: Classical windows error message that application crashed. APPCRASH is it's name. NOTHING is being done after malloc, cause the program crashes at the line of malloc :(.

Comment: @Lordink: again, post a [minimum compilable example](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, there really was a problem in other part of the code AFTER malloc, I have not suspected this before. Question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good:

```
struct Customer* ph;
ph = (struct Customer*)malloc(line_count * sizeof(struct Customer));
```

Better:

```
struct Customer* ph =
  (struct Customer*)malloc(line_count * sizeof(struct Customer));
if (!ph) {
  <<error handling>>
  ...
```

But frankly, it sounds like the problem is elsewhere in your code.

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your malloc().

Maybe "line_count" is bogus, maybe "malloc()" is failing (in which case, it should return "NULL") ... or maybe you're accessing the struct incorrectly and/or failing to initialize it correctly.

A stack traceback of the actual crash would be *very* useful.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code you are showing might crash only if `ph == NULL` after the `malloc` call and you dereference it.

From the `malloc` man page:

> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated
>   memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable.  On error,
>   these functions return  NULL. NULL may also be returned by a
>   successful call to malloc() with a size of zero, or by a successful
>   call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.

Comment: The thing is - nothing is being done after the malloc. The program crashes just at it's line.